# Android Toolbar Tab Navigation

Tags: android, toolbar, android-tabs, android-toolbar

How would you add tabs inline with the actionbar (tabs on the same row as the settings button)?

[Google's DeskClock Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMmHR.png)

I believe they accomplish this using deprecated methods even on the marshmallow release branch:

```
mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(0);
mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

They style with:

```
<style name="DeskClock" parent="@style/BaseActivityTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/default_background</item>
        <!-- Attributes from support.v7.appcompat -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/DeskClockActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/DeskClockTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/DeskClockTabBarStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DeskClockTabBaseStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/actionbar_tab_padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/actionbar_tab_padding</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DeskClockTabStyle" parent="DeskClockTabBaseStyle">
        <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DeskClockTabBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <!-- Attributes from support.v7.appcompat -->
        <item name="showDividers">none</item>
    </style>
    <style name="DeskClockActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@null</item>
        <!--suppress CheckTagEmptyBody Empty displayOptions to hide app title at launch. -->
        <item name="displayOptions"></item>
    </style>
```

**Edit:**

I still do not achieve the same effect.

[My attempt looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NShDX.png)

Style:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

        <!-- Attributes from support.v7.appcompat -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/DeskClockActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/DeskClockTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/DeskClockTabBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DeskClockTabBaseStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/actionbar_tab_padding</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/actionbar_tab_padding</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DeskClockTabStyle" parent="DeskClockTabBaseStyle">
        <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DeskClockTabBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <!-- Attributes from support.v7.appcompat -->
        <item name="showDividers">none</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DeskClockActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@null</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@null</item>
        <!--suppress CheckTagEmptyBody Empty displayOptions to hide app title at launch. -->
        <item name="displayOptions"></item>
    </style>
```

MainActivity:

```
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayOptions(0);
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        mActionBar.addTab(
                mActionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create in-line tabs on a toolbar, you must create a custom view for it.

actionbar_layout.xml (specifically note android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal")

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity

```
 actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
 actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

If it works for you:

You can use [PagerSlidingStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)

Remove the default actionBar and customize your slidingtabstrip to your content, and the from XML add the settings button and inflate the menu on opening.

I believe this is achievable, though I never used it in this situation.

Comment: How would I add the settings button in XML? There's no way to do this without removing the default action bar?

I also included Google's styling. Does that help? I could even use the deprecated methods if need be.

Comment: I don't really use the default actionBar, I find it very difficult to customize in the current API. For now, a custom actionBar is almost always the best solution. You could add the button in XML and set an onClickListener to that button, and then inflate a dialog just below the button.